# ASP.NET MVC is not deployed completely

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

Good morning everyone!

My question is probably super simple. Let me start from the beginning.
I created a ASP.NET MVC ,web app. Then, I added a model and controller. Apply migration and updated database. I used **Entity Framework**.  Done!
Everything works in my local environment fine. However, I could not publish my app successfully.
After publishing, my web app available. Also, I was able to access custom pages such as Home, Contact, About, Register and Login. When I try to reach the recently created one, I got that error:

```
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 0HLRSM19R6O8C:00000001

Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application.
```

I think it happens because I deployed only app itself but not MySQL database. I have student subscription in Azure(just in case). 
If I am right, how can I deploy my app to azure with database?

Thank you!

Comment: Please open your web.config file and turn off custom errors so that it shows detail error message.

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you provided is too broad. Try to turn off `customErrors` in web.config to get some helpful error message.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> how can I deploy my app to azure with database?

You could refer to this [article](https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs.html) to deploy webapp with database to azure.
Using the following picture, you will point out the sql database connectionstring at runtime.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It helped. Interestingly, I did the same steps before and It did not work. Right now, it works!